# BackgroundWork services in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire, background-service

I recently came across an article regarding background work / scheduled work management using ASP.NET.

As per my understanding of Web applications, you can run a bunch of sync and async requests until the browser is connected with the Server. Once the browser is closed, the request line is broken.

I have read the documentation of Hangfire ([www.hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io/)) and it describes itself as:

> Hangfire is an open-source framework that helps you to create, process
> and manage your background jobs, i.e. operations you don't want to put
> in your request processing pipeline

My question is, are these framework Server based? Like can they run the tasks even when there is no user connection with the web server?

If they can run independently can I control a background thread across multiple web applications?